# Redirection of middleware in scrapy is not working

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to implement login using python scrapy. However, the login is not working. I was referring to below code

```
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
# from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


class LoginSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'loginspider'
    login_page = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/login'
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/login']
    username = 'foobar'
    password = 'foobar'

    def init_request(self):
        return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.start_requests)

    def start_requests(self):
        print("\n start_request is here \n")
        yield Request(
            url=self.login_page, callback=self.login, dont_filter=True)

    def login(self, response):
        print("\n Login is here! \n")
        token = response.xpath(
            '//*[@name="csrf_token"]/@value').extract_first()
        return FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={
                'csrf_token': token,
                'password': 'foobar',
                'username': 'foobar'
            },
            callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        print("\n Check_login_response \n")
        if b"Learn" in response.body:
            print("Worked, logged in")
            #return self.parse_item
        else:
            print("Not logged in")
            return


process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(LoginSpider)
process.start()
```

From the above code instead of hard coding the credentials I change the code as it as below

```
 def fetch_form_data(self,response):
        if all(field in response.text for field in self.credentials['fields_in_response']):
            inputs =response.xpath('//form//input').extract()
            soup_dict={}
            for key,i in enumerate(inputs):
                soup = BeautifulSoup(i, 'html.parser')
                inp_type   =   soup.input['type'] if soup.input.has_attr('type') else None
                inp_value  =   soup.input['value'] if soup.input.has_attr('value')  else None
                inp_name   =   soup.input['name'] if soup.input.has_attr('name')  else None
                soup_dict[key]= {'name':inp_name,'value':inp_value,'type':inp_type}
            login_cred= self.credentials['login_details']
            form_data={}
            for key,value in soup_dict.items():
                if value['name'] != None and value['type'] == 'text':
                    form_data[value['name']]=login_cred['name']
                elif value['name'] != None and value['type'] == 'password':
                    form_data[value['name']]=login_cred['pwd']
                elif value['name'] != None and value['type'] == 'hidden':
                    form_data[value['name']]=value['value']
                else:
                    pass
            return form_data      

    def login(self, response):
        print ("\n Login is here! \n")
        formdata=self.fetch_form_data(response)         
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
        formdata,
        callback=self.check_login_response)
```

But now the login is not working. I think I'm missing something in these. Could someone please suggest to me  what is it

One thing I noticed the difference  when running the script is[image]

When the first script is run actually there is redirection is happened by middleware.
[image]
When replacing with second script it redirection is not working

Comment: @Kevin C Could you Please go through it

Comment: @user8389458 Please look into it

Comment: @MrPandav Please help

Answer (score 0):

The function login() is inside the function fetch_form_data()...

Comment: Can you explain? I used to fetch_form_data () for my requirment

Comment: I need to scrap the form data then fill with credentials that why I'm using an extra function

Comment: You can run the first code and replace the function in first code with second code then you will find the difference

Answer (score 0):

Change `return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata,callback=self.check_login_response)`  to  `return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata=formdata,
callback=self.check_login_response)`